# textmate move cursor without using the arrow keys

Tags: editor, textmate

I'm in an ergonomic sort of mood, and realizing that I waste many precious milliseconds by lifting my hands up from the letter keys over to the arrow keys in order to move my cursor. Is there a handy alterate way to move the cursor I can access in Textmate?

Generally, I'm looking for ways to keep my head up more while programming. I'd like to, for example, be able to copy an entire line into the clipboard without lifting my fingers. Can textmate take me where I want to go, or should I start thinking about making a move to Vim or some such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> moves cursor one character forward
<kbd>ctrl+b</kbd> .. and backward

(hold <kbd>alt/option</kbd> to skip by word)

<kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> beginning of line
<kbd>ctrl+e</kbd> .. and end of line

<kbd>ctrl+n</kbd> move to next line
<kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> .. and to previous